# Union of two arrays alternating the value?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I have two arrays of char: a,b. How can i create with a loop "for" the new array vet, which is the union of the two alternating array a, b?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[] = "BNSIO";
    char b[] = "EISM\a";
    char vet[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)); i++) {

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)); i++){
        printf("%c", vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know that `a` and `b` are the same size?

Comment: `char vet[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)];` This is allocating 1 byte too much, since you are allocating space for two null terminators. Correct code would be: `sizeof(a)-1 + sizeof(b)-1 + ... + sizeof(n)-1 + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For alternating values from both arrays, try this (assuming lengths are equal):

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char a[] = "BNSIO";
    char b[] = "EISM\a";
    char vet[sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)];

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++) {
        vet[2*i] = a[i];
        vet[2*i+1] = b[i];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(vet) ; i++){
        printf("%c", vet[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work when the sizes of a and b are different, at least put a check in the code to see if the sizes are same

Comment: @novice - I agree. I thought of doing the whole differnet sizes thing (run parallel on both until the first one ends, then finish off the other one), but the question talks about getting a result of alternating between the arrays - which implies same length. Preferred to give a short coherent solution for the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
for (int i = 0,j=0,k=0; k < (sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) -2);) 
{
    if(i+1<sizeof(a))
    {
        vet[k] = a[i];
        i++;k++;
    }
    if(j+1<sizeof(b))
    {
        vet[k] = b[j];
        j++;k++;
    }       
}
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)-2); i++){
    printf("%c", vet[i]);
}
```

You need to subtract 1 for the null terminating character